# Django, adding excluded properties to the submitted modelform

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, modelform

I've a modelform and I excluded two fields, the `create_date` and the `created_by` fields. Now I get the "Not Null" error when using the `save()` method because the `created_by` is empty.

I've tried to add the user id to the form before the `save()` method like this: `form.cleaned_data['created_by'] = 1` and `form.cleaned_data['created_by_id'] = 1`. But none of this works.

Can someone explain to me how I can 'add' additional stuff to the submitted modelform so that it will save?

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        exclude = ('created_by', 'create_date', )
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since you have excluded the fields `created_by` and `create_date` in your form, trying to assign them through `form.cleaned_data` does not make any sense.

Here is what you can do:

If you have a view, you can simply use `form.save(commit=False)` and then set the value of `created_by`

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LocationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.created_by = request.user
            obj.save()
        ...
        ...
```

`

If you are using the Admin, you can override the [save_model()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) method to get the desired result.

```
class LocationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.created_by = request.user
        obj.save()
```

Comment: Seriously, the Pony would be proud.

Comment: The above was not working for me. In my ModelForm Meta, I was specifying the fields to include, instead of exclude. Turned out the problem was I was using the class variable "include", when I should have been using "fields". Thus the fields I wanted to exclude were being included and the form would not validate.

Comment: In case the aforementioned approaches don't work, you can use another approach: do not exclude the field you want to _hide_ and overwrite it with a custom _hidden_ widget as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59893460/1636885

Answer (score 6):

Pass a user as a parameter to form constructor, then use it to set created_by field of a model instance:

```
def add_location(request):
    ...
    form = LocationForm(user=request.user)
    ...

class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(forms.ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.instance.created_by = user
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution is to pass an instance of the object with pre-filled fields to the model form's constructor. That way the fields will be populated at validation time. Assigning values after `form.save()` may result in validation errors if fields are required.

```
LocationForm(request.POST or None, instance=Location(
    created_by=request.user,
    create_date=datetime.now(),
))
```

Notice that instance is an unsaved object, so the id will not be assigned until form saves it.

Comment: I personally feel this is a better approach

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by using form.save(commit=False) ([doc](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method))

That will return an object instance of the model class without committing it to the database.

So, your processing might look something like this:

```
form = some_form(request.POST)
location = form.save(commit=False)
user = User(pk=1)
location.created_by = user
location.create_date = datetime.now()
location.save()
```

Comment: note that you also have to make a call to form's save_m2m() method

Comment: True, if there are many-to-many relations attached to the model.