# Why is Django giving me this "violates not-null constraint" error?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

The error:

> null value in column "postal_code_id" violates not-null constraint

The form:

```
def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        address_form = AddressForm(request.POST)
        company_form = CompanyForm(request.POST)
        if address_form.is_valid() and company_form.is_valid():
            print address_form.cleaned_data['postal_code'] # <-- prints (<PostalCode: V4N 1K6>, False)
            address_form.save() # <------------------------------- occurs here
        else:
            print 'Address errors',address_form.errors
            print 'Company errors', company_form.errors
    else:
        address_form = AddressForm()
        company_form = CompanyForm()
    return render(request, 'company/add.html', locals())
```

Clearly the form does have a valid `PostalCode` object, so I'm not sure why it's saying it violates the not-null constraint. Of course, I am doing something kinda funny with the form:

```
class AddressForm(ModelForm):
    postal_code = CharField(max_length=10, validators=[validate_postal_code])
    city = CharField(max_length=50, validators=[validate_non_whitespace])
    province = CharField(max_length=50, validators=[validate_non_whitespace])
    country = CharField(max_length=50, initial='Canada', validators=[validate_non_whitespace])

    def clean_postal_code(self):
        code = self.cleaned_data['postal_code']
        code = code.upper()
        code = re.sub('[^A-Z0-9]', '', code)
        code = code[:3] + ' ' + code[-3:]
        return code

    def clean_country(self):
        country = self.cleaned_data['country']

        try:
            country = Country.objects.get(name__iexact=country)
        except Country.DoesNotExist:
            raise ValidationError('Country does not exist')

        return country

    def clean_province(self):
        province = self.cleaned_data['province']

        if not Province.objects.filter(name__iexact=province).exists():
            raise ValidationError('Province does not exist')

        return province

    def clean(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data

        if 'country' in data and 'province' in data:
            try:
                data['province'] = Province.objects.get(country=data['country'], name__iexact=data['province'])
                if 'city' in data:
                    data['city'] = City.objects.get_or_create(name__iexact=data['city'], province=data['province'], defaults={'name':data['city']})[0]
                    if 'postal_code' in data:
                        data['postal_code'] = PostalCode.objects.get_or_create(code=data['postal_code'], city=data['city'])
            except Province.DoesNotExist:
                self._errors['province'] = self.error_class(['Province does not exist in that Country'])
                del data['province']

        return data

    class Meta:
        exclude = ['postal_code']
        model = Address
```

Specifically, I'm replacing the `postal_code` field with a text field and then I find/create the object in the "clean" method. Why does that confuse Django? It's getting the object it needs in the end, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're excluding `postal_code`, which will cause the model form to skip over the field later on during the save attempt. I've had a similar problem, and had to trace through django code to figure out the behaviour. It's worth doing by the way.

What you want to do instead, is set the widget used for the postal_code field instead of excluding then including.

```
class AddressForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        widgets = {
            'postal_code': CharField(max_length=10),
        }
```

That should allow the modelform to validate the field correctly and save it. I excluded the rest of your form for brevity.

Edit:

Attempting to use a CharField for a ForeignKey is fraught with horrible in a ModelForm. Instead, convert it to a regular form. You already appear to be defining most of your fields anyway. Then the reliance is on you to validate that fields are valid, and are members of the database already. Create a save method that behaves like the ModelForm save method, and away you go.

Comment: Hah! Brilliant. Forgot I had excluded the `postal_code`. That, and I needed a `[0]` on `PostalCode.objects.get_or_create` (it was returning a tuple). Removing the exclude fixes it, but doing it `widgets` instead causes this error `'CharField' object has no attribute 'value_from_datadict'` instead. Would you know why that is?

Comment: @mark Sorry, I didn't read your question clearly enough. Since postal_code is a foreign key, the field expects an id (not a text field) when it attempts to convert the POST data into a field within the form. That would be why it's failing. I've had to deal with this before, and the easiest way is to define your own custom form (not a modelform), and handle the save method yourself. You don't have very many fields, so it shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Hrm... I'll continue doing it this way for now (overwriting the field), but I'll keep that in mind if this becomes problematic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Django, but perhaps you have to make sure that the postal code is saved before you try to save the address?

Comment: Good theory, but `get_or_create` does create the object in the database. Just checked, it is indeed there.

Answer (score 1):

I came to this question because I was trying to automatically add an `uploaded_by` field to form data before the form was saved. I was using a `ModelForm`, with `uploaded_by` excluded. I found that the answer to a [related stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831845/django-adding-excluded-properties-to-the-submitted-modelform) was a succinct solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I arrived at this question since I was getting that IntegrityError error when I tried to submit a ModelForm instance which had a CharField with `blank=True` (yep, `null=True` should never be used with CharField). The problem was in the form itself: the respective field's `clean_field()` method was checking for existence of the field's value first, but if the value did not exist, it returned `None`, which is exactly why not-null constraint was violated. Fixing the method to return the same `cleaned_data['field']` that was checked for a value solved the problem.